# How to put a new picture in an iPhone image frame

Tags: gimp, iphone, screenshot

I want to change the screen part of this Iphone image with the screen capture of my own app. I'm trying to do this in Gimp (unless there is a better way?). However, I can't seem to just copy paste my screenshot on the map part.

Is there a better way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't copy and pasting work?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this kind of compositing is to cut out the map completely, so that you have a frame that's transparent in the image area, then put your own image on a layer below. That eliminates alignment problems.

I don't off-hand recall the specifics of how Gimp does this, but it certainly has the capability.

Answer (score 1):

So,as Alan had put it - one of the easiest ways to achieve this, is to cut out
the image area, and leave the phone frame with a transparent window.

You then add any desired image in a separate layer, bellow the cut-out frame, and export it.

Step by step:

1. Import your image above into GIMP
2. On the Layers dialog (`ctrl + L`), right click on the layer with the your image (should be the only one) and choose "Add alpha channel" on the context menu. (maybe this was the step you were missing. Without it, GIMP keeps imported images without transparency, if they weren't transparent to start with)
3. Use the rectangular selection tool to select the map area. You can combine it with various zoom levels, and I think the rect select tool is the best in its category to allow precise selections. As an extra hint: you can hover the mouse over a handle of the rectangle, and fine tune it with the arrow keys on the keyboard. Having a pixel-exact rectangular selection in GIMP is a breeze!
4. `Edit->cut`
5. `File->Open as layers...` and choose the image you want to put there
   instead of the map
6. The new layer opens above the phone frame - go back to the Layer's dialog, and bring it down along the stack, pressing the "down" arrow
7. `File->Save" to have an XCF file that have the phone mask as a separate layer, so you just have to do steps "5" and "6" for other images
8. `File->Export` to export your final image to a PNG file you can use in other programs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try PicApp.net which works like this:

1. You upload the original image to the tool.
2. You drag the green rectangle's corners to the place where the screenshot is located (this is the way to tell the tool where it should place your screen capture).
3. You upload your screen capture and it will be placed inside the original image. At the end you can download the customized image - free or paid.

Here's a video that shows how this work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuX5TdcoYrk

Let me know if you need any help - I'm part of the PicApp.net team.

Answer (score -1):

Although cutting out the map is one of the solutions,
why not try using some awesome free mock-ups around the internet.

[**Freebiesbug**](http://freebiesbug.com/) has some cool ones.